# Prevent an overwriting a value in dictanery in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

How to prevent the overwriting of a value in dictionary in python and check the highest value in the same dictionary

```
is_other_user=True
while is_other_user:
  name = input("Enter your name please: ")
  bid= int(input("Enter your bid price please: "))
  def auction(user_name,user_bid):
    auction_info={}
    auction_info[user_name]=user_bid
            
  other_user=input("Is there other users who want to bit 'yes' 'no' ")
  if other_user=="no":
    is_other_user=False
    auction(name,bid)
    print("Goodbye")
  else:
    auction(name,bid)`
```

Comment: Move the `auction_info` dict outside of the inner function

Comment: First, don't define a function in each loop, in any case define it once outside the `while` and then call it in the iterations. Second, that function is not returning any value. The way it's written, it does nothing.

Comment: Whether `other_user == "no"`, or else, you always try call `auction`. So, why not just writing what the function is supposed to do once, outside the `if` - `else`, and then, `if  other_user == "no":` set `is_other_user=False` and print "Good bye"?